# Is there a way to upgrade the GM Intellilink System?

Tags: vauxhall, corsa

*I wasn't really sure where to ask this, but since it is about my car I decided this might be the best place.*

I've had my Vauxhall Corsa just under a year now, and there have been no official updates for the Intellilink system as was hinted by the salesman.

I have since found out that the Intellilink system runs on Windows CE, which was a pleasant surprise to me.

Are there any images of Windows CE with the software installed so I can have a tinker with it?

Comment: Good question! I don't have any experience with these systems, but hopefully someone will chime in. This is, by the way, *very much* on-topic. Thanks for stopping by to ask!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 . I've just watched a video on how to alter the wallpaper so it peaked my curiosity.

Comment: I guess my question is does the Intellilink system offer storage space or is it ROM based? Either way you could probably dump the contents of the ROM/HD. I doubt you'd be able to find an image from a legitimate source. Since it would seemingly fall under software piracy issues.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDPimox8pnE - How to get into developer mode http://www.corsaeforums.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1775&start=20 - Useful forum topic. Most useful so far: http://www.corsaeforums.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1691&start=10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the firmware by entering developer mode and then going to the explorer mode in the developer options menu.

EDIT: I have also mirrored the file on my MEGA in case it disappears or is deleted.

[From this forum thread](http://www.corsaeforums.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1691&start=20)

> First off, I accept no responsibility if you brick your head unit you
>   are going too need to modify files stored on it to enable Mirrorlink.
>
> Ok so the file should for all uk cars, even the russian one is
>   incredibly similar.
>
> I recommend you use a stylus for this, (I used a pen with the lid on)
>
> 1) Download ClientAppInfo.bin from here
>   https://mega.nz/#!Rs0QiBAD!NWVV3Xy5RJwSomJkwW-ZgIMoWUlzcZZpT2lOjocm4ww This is the one
>   I have modified from my Corsa LE so should work with yours no problem.
>
> Check the fil, here http://onlinemd5.com/, the sha and md5 should
>   match
>
> SHA1 77720003DFD1E9476D8EA84FD892675A198500F2
>
> MD5 0410F2CA7F0A959E3E39DF604416D5B6
>
> 2) Put it on a pen drive formatted to fat32, most likely what it is
>   already formatted too.
>
> 3) Go to your car turn it on and wait for intellilink to start.
>
> 4) Enable developer mode, 
>   -Tap repeatedly in the top left corner unit a window appears asking you to enter a code. 
>   -Enter 20110827 and press ok, nothing will happen that you can immediately see but you have turned it on in the settings.
>
> 5) Go to explorer mode
>   - From the main menu go to settings, on page 3 you should have developer menu, if not repeat step 4.
>   - In the developer menu scroll to Explorer Mode, press it and it will launch Windows CE.
>
> 6) Copy the files
>   - Plug in the usb drive
>   - From the desktop press on my device in the top left it looks like a yellow palm pilot 
>   - Go into the MD folder, this is your pendrive
>   - Press on the file so it is highlighted, in the toolbar at the top click edit and then copy (you'll understand why I say use a stylus it's small)
>
> 6.5) Change folder options
>   - In the toolbar press View and select options
>   - Untick all the options shown and press ok
>
> 7) Replace the original file
>   - At the middle of the toolbar on the top is a yellow folder press it and you should return to the my device screen with all the folders
>   - Navigate to /Storage Card/System
>   - In the top toolbar press Edit and then Paste, It will ask do you want to override the file, press yes.
>   - Wait for it to copy
>
> 8) Restart Car
>   - Remove the pen drive
>   - Turn off your car and wait for the handbrake light to turn off, this can take around 30 seconds be patient
>   - Turn it back on and in the apps you should see Mirrorlink
>
> I'll take some pictures soon to show you, but in the meantime watch the
>   video , yes its in russian but the windows CE stuff is all in english
>   so it should give you a good idea of what to do. In the video he also
>   replaces the file in storage card 2, I didn't have the same folder
>   there so just skipped that part.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0qp2cRK4KQ&list=WL

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure this is the same version as mine, the menus look completely different. I have the Corsa Excite 2015 model.

Comment: Apparently the systems are similar though. I wouldn't try installing the package, but I'd suggest seeing if you can get into the developer window and explorer mode.

Comment: K, thanks. I'll look in to it more. And, yes, I got in to dev mode and Changed the wall paper.

Comment: As if you access the actual operating system there may be a way to upgrade it.